# Golang prometheus: is there a way to measure metrics for outbound requests?

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics

I have a service A where I am scrapping metrics using prometheus, A makes some outbound requests to another service B. Is there a way to get metrics for requets from A to B?

Like, I want a measure count and duration of requets from A -> B

Comment: Take a look at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp#example-InstrumentRoundTripperDuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metrics can be record by using `prometheus.NewCounterVec` and `prometheus.NewHistogramVec` (or `proemetheus.NewSummaryVec`, depends on the use case).

We could use custom [labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#labels) to identify who is the client and  who is the server. By this way, can filter out a client's `request count` and `duration` metrics to a particular server.

Here is the sample snippet

**client.go**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

var (
    requestCounter = prometheus.NewCounterVec(
        prometheus.CounterOpts{
            Name: "client_request_count",
            Help: "Total number of requests from client",
        },
        []string{"client", "server", "method", "route", "status"},
    )

    durationHistorgram = prometheus.NewHistogramVec(
        prometheus.HistogramOpts{
            Name:    "client_request_duration_secs",
            Help:    "Duration of requests from Client",
            Buckets: []float64{0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5},
        },
        []string{"client", "server", "method", "route", "status"},
    )
)

func init() {
    prometheus.MustRegister(requestCounter)
    prometheus.MustRegister(durationHistorgram)
}

func main() {

    e := echo.New()
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {

        // the request start time
        start := time.Now()
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8002", nil)
        if err != nil {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        }

        resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        labels := prometheus.Labels{
            "client": "Server A", // defines the client server
            "server": "Server B", // defines the outbound request server
            "method": "GET",// HTTP method
            "route":  "/", // Request route
            "status": resp.Status,// Response status
        }
        duration := time.Since(start).Seconds()

        // the duration
        durationHistorgram.With(labels).Observe(duration)

        // request api count
        requestCounter.With(labels).Inc()

        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "[Client -> Server] Request send and received")
    })

    e.GET("/metrics", echo.WrapHandler(promhttp.Handler()))

    if err := e.Start(":8001"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**server.go**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, map[string]interface{}{
            "message": "response sending from server",
        })
    })

    if err := e.Start(":8002"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, these are our custom labels.

```
 []string{"client", "server", "method", "route", "status"},
```

and these are the label values

```
labels := prometheus.Labels{
            "client": "Server A", // defines the client server
            "server": "Server B", // defines the outbound request server
            "method": "GET", // HTTP method
            "route":  "/", // Request route
            "status": resp.Status,// Response status
        }
```

and finally we can query

```
client_request_count {client="Server A", server="Server B"}
```

*The request Server A send to the Server B*

[image]

**References**

- [Prometheus HistorGram](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram)
- [Prometheus Summary](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#summary)
- [Histogram And Summary](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/)
- [Examples](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/tree/main/examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement interceptor for http requests - https://morioh.com/p/c67b06c88598

Capture start and end time for the requests to calculate the duration. Also increment the gauge counter to get the number of requests made from service A to Service B.